# real method invoke mock method but not work

Tags: mockito

i spy a object to test a method

```
List<HighWay> mockedList = mock(List.class);
request = Mockito.spy(new HighWayRequest());
Mockito.doReturn(mockedList).when(request).getHighWays();
request.updateNewHighWay(repository);
```

the updateNewHighWay method invoke getHighWays method which i want to return list,
and real method of request is like that

```
public void updateNewHighWay(HighWayRepository repository) {
        List<HighWay> total = getHighWays();
        List<HighWay> willSave = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
        for (HighWay highWay : total) {
            if (!repository.exists(highWay.getId())) {
                willSave.add(highWay);
                repository.save(highWay);
            }
        }
        while (total.size() == willSave.size()) {
            total = getHighWays();
            willSave = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
            for (HighWay highWay : total) {
                if (!repository.exists(highWay.getId())) {
                    willSave.add(highWay);
                    repository.save(highWay);
                }
            }
        }
    }
public List<HighWay> getHighWays() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

but the reality it throws nullexception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   chinahighway.HighWayRequest.updateNewHighWay(HighWayRequest.java:206)
>     at chinahighway.HttpTest.testpageinsert(HttpTest.java:269)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

why the doReturn not work? how to let getHighWays method return my wanted list?

plz help me thanks very much!

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? Which line does it refer to? Is your class final?

Comment: i have add the exception log

Comment: Which line does it refer to? Is your class final?

Comment: for (HighWay highWay : total this statement

Comment: Is your class final? That's the third time I ask you this question, BTW.

Comment: sorry for my careless，it is not final class

Comment: I'd say that since you return a mockedList, its iterator() method returns null, which is why you get an NPE. If you want an empty list, then make the getHighways() method return an empty list, not a mocked list.

Comment: thanks you very much，i am new to mockito，if i Do not want its iterator return null，i should spy it？

Comment: Just because you use Mockito doesn't mean that everything should be mocked or spied. A value object like a List should generally not be mocked or spied. If the list's role is to contain value for your method under test to use, then create an ArrayList and populate it with these values. If the goal is for the list to be populated by your method under test, then create an empty ArrayList and check that it contains what it should after the method call.